# How to link to all of your apps (developer page) in the AppStore - iOS7

Tags: ios6, app-store, uri, ios7, url-scheme

There has been alot of confusion on how to link to your apps in the AppsTore, especially since none of the old solutions work with iOS7. I seem to have found a way to do it and still have it work on the old iOS devices after hours of my own research turning up nothing I figured I would post the solutions I created here Q&A style.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Step 1: open iTunes on your LAPTOP.

Step 2: go to one of your apps.

Step 3: in the top left corner you will see your company name, right click on it and select copy link.

I get something like this: `https://itunes.apple.com/us/artist/apps4life/id293274590`

Change the "https://" to "itms-apps://"

My final link looks like this: `itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/us/artist/apps4life/id293274590`

Opening that link on an iOS device should open the AppStore directly and load your apps in a list by best-sellers.

*(*Note, this URL says "/us/" in it... Can anyone outside of the US test this and verify that it works? If not, we would simple use the iOS device to detect the users locale settings and then change the "/us/" to whatever is needed. I tried changing mine to /ca/ and I live in the USA and the link still worked, just want to verify that it works for everyone else and it still lets you make purchases even though you are in a different country's AppStore. Everything seems to work here in the USA though! Even for other country's AppStores.)*

Comment: I tried this and it showed my only iPad app but only 1 of my 46 iPhone apps... strange.  I guess that might be an app store bug (i.e. Im not saying this url is necessarily wrong)

Comment: Work perfect on iOS 7!

Comment: @CharlieSeligman the apps that are shown depend on the device you are using. While clicking that link on an iPad, the overview shows iPad and universal apps only. Same for iPhone: only iPhone + universal apps here.